# jquery selector problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using this code:

```
$('fieldset input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {if($(this).attr('checked','checked')){
    var switches = $(this).parent().find('.switch');
    $(switches).attr('state','on')
    $(switches).css({'left':"52px"});
    $(switches).parent().css({'background-position': "147px -37px"});
}})
```

But somehow it sets all my checkboxes to `checked="checked"` Am I just stupid or is something else in the code interfering?

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT:
here is the HTML

```
<fieldset>
        <input checked="checked" />
        <label></label>
        <div class="toggle_box">
            <div class="switch" state="on"></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input/>
        <label></label>
        <div class="toggle_box">
            <div class="switch"></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `checked` value to `attr()` as the second argument. That causes it to be set. What's then returned is the jQuery object with that `input`, which is always a truthy value.

Your if condition should look like this (use the `:checked` pseudo-class instead):

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

On a side note, your inner code can be refactored to this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.switch')
    .attr('state', 'on')
    .css({ 'left': "52px" })
    .parent()
        .css({ 'background-position': "147px -37px" });
```

If you *have* to use a cached variable (i.e. `switches`), you can, but *don't wrap it in the jQuery function*. It's a jQuery object itself, so needs not be wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code is doing it...

```
$(this).attr('checked','checked')
```

...which returns the set in order for the cascade to work. An `Object` is always *truthy* in JavaScript.

Try...

```
this.checked
```

...which returns whether the checkbox is checked or not. If you wanted to do it the jQuery way, use `$(this).is(':checked')`. I wouldn't though, it's more verbose and less performant.

Comment: I think the right term would be chaining, not cascading (that's for CSS).

Comment: @BoltClock It's called the *cascade* by Douglas Crockford. I guess it can be called both.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the if statement is setting your checkboxes to checked. Particularly, this statement: `$(this).attr('checked','checked')`.

Instead you can do `if($(this).prop('checked'))`

Read more about the [jQuery Prop method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Alternatively, you can do, `this.checked` which will access the DOM directly or with jQuery, `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).attr('checked','checked'))` would be your problem.  You're assigning `checked` to each checkbox instead of checking if it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I see you're using `.is('checked')` when I beleive you want `.is(':checked')` The preceding colon being the difference.

UPDATE:  I see you updated the code.  The line

```
if ($(this).attr('checked', 'checked'))
```

is actually setting all 'input:checkbox' elements to checked.  It should be:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('fieldset input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()  {if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')){
var switches = $(this).parent().find('.switch');
$(switches).attr('state','on')
$(switches).css({'left':"52px"});
$(switches).parent().css({'background-position': "147px -37px"});
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a selector specifically for the checked boxes.

```
$('fieldset input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    var switches = $(this).parent().find('.switch');
    $(switches).attr('state','on')
    $(switches).css({'left':'52px'});
    $(switches).parent().css({'background-position':'147px -37px'});
});
```

If you use that you won't have to do any of that logic by yourself.